# Sum the field of a relationship table into the source table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have created a relationship between two feature classes(one to many) and i want to have the sum of a field in tableB(many) into a cell in TableA (one), TableA is states and tableB is roads within the state, so i want the sum of roads in each state(in a field in tableA). 
I have created one to many relationship class between two feature classes (not shapefile) within the same database, these feature classes have attribute tables (A, one and B, many). So i want sum of a field(colunm) from tableB into tableA.
I hope it is clear know.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What have you tried?  Can you please [edit] your question to include a sample of each dataset, and how they relate to each other?

Comment: Also perhaps include some info about what format your data are in, ie shapefile, database, etc.  That may help give options to solve the problem.

Comment: By relationship table do you mean relationship class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to store a new attribute in the relationship class called `SumRoadLength` which will contain the sum of the length or other attribute from the `Roads` feature class.

Take a look at this page: [Relationship class properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/relationship-class-properties.htm). You can [copy-paste attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/editing-the-attributes-of-related-features.htm) between the origin-destination however there is no concept of calculated or computed fields and triggers that you have in a DBMS. In other words, editing the length of a road in a particular state won't update the `SumRoadLength` field in the relationship class.

I don't know other moving parts of your workflow, but I'd recommend taking a look at ModelBuilder or Python if you would like to automate the workflow of updating the information between feature classes. You could also manually run the [Summary Statistics](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) GP tool. Here is a sample of calculating the total population of all cities within every state.

[image]

Then join the output table to your states feature class using the [Add Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm) or [Join Field](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm) GP tools.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Alex, it worked for me using model builder, but the only problem is that i should delete the sum field every time i want to run the model (update it),(another field for the sum is joining to the state table), any way its the best solotion so far.

Comment: Good. You don't have to delete the field every time you need to do update. Just add join for the field with another name, calculate existing field (sum_length) and then remove the join.